# How to save changes of a docker container when you are in the container

Tags: docker, containers, commit

When I run a docker container and have some changes I want to save, I only know one way:

1. open another window and run `docker ps`
2. copy the container id and run `docker commit <container id> .../...:tag`
3. go back to the initial window and `exit`

OS: MacOS

How can I save the changes without opening another window? Or what is the most efficient or most used way to do it.

Comment: As a general rule, you should never run `docker commit` (and avoid being "in" a container or needing to "save" anything).  Have you read the official Docker tutorial on [building and running custom images](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/)?  That's the more standard way to set up this sequence.